# jQuery - move dynamic script to just before closing body tag in DNN/Evoq

Tags: jquery, append, dotnetnuke

I'm using DNN/Evoq and I've written a custom js file and I want it to load just before the closing `</body>`.

DNN/Evoq is somewhat limiting (from my understanding) in how skin files load and it's done automatically and it's loading file just before the opening `<body>`.

Nonetheless, I'm thinking if there's a way to write some jQuery to grab that script text (`<script src="/Portals/_default/Skins/Site/js/custom.js?cdv=306">`) and move to just before closing `</body>` that could potentially do the trick, but not sure how to accomplish using jQuery. Any ideas on how to do this?

**UPDATE**
Was able to solve using DNN's `SkinPath` variable like so: `<script src="<%=SkinPath%>js/[file_name]"></script>`

Comment: Do you *have* to move the script? Could you not update the js to wait for the DOM to have loaded before initialising its methods?

Comment: I was able to solve (see answer for update), however, not sure if this is a good method/best practice to accomplish this. Any DNNers have any thoughts?

Comment: Your update does nothing about *moving* the script to before the `</body>`. Did I misinterpret the question?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to force to the bottom you can use the dnnCSSInclude skin object, or client API and use the "ForceProvider" property.  If you set it to "DnnFormBottomProvider" that will render the item at the bottom of the form.  (Which is closest to the closing body tag.)

Full documentation [is here](http://www.dnnsoftware.com/wiki/client-resource-management-api)